# How acceptable is it to publish an article without the author's knowledge?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

A few years after finishing my PhD, I was notified by my former supervisor that they had submitted without my knowledge a section of my PhD dissertation to a journal, listing me as first author and adding other team members as co-authors. They had litterally copied the section verbatim, without adjusting it to reduce the verbosity and to follow the outline a journal article usually has, even keeping in references to other paragraphs in the dissertation that didn't make sense anymore out of context.
The paper was accepted shortly after.

Is it an acceptable practice to do so?

What could I have done to prevent the publication of this article at the time?

--
For context, I hadn't been in touch with my former lab in between the end of my PhD and this event, and the field is systems biology.

Comment: @Ootagu This was a journal with low requirements I would say. To clarify, the references were to ideas or points discussed elsewhere in the dissertation

Comment: Do you object to its publication or is the question for information only?

Comment: @Buffy The paper has been published for a while now, so this is is mostly for information about what were my options then. What happened was definitely very strange, and I didn't really know how to react at the time. I would have liked the paper not be published. FWIW I had never heard of that journal before, and wondered whether maybe my former supervisor knew someone there.

Comment: The answer of gnometorule here seems complete and accurate. No reputable journal should _ever_ permit this. No professor should _ever_ attempt it. Bad actors all round.

Comment: I wouldn't say the story is strange.  The usual understanding is that all (or most) research will end up with one or more publications.  The supervisors may have told the student at an earlier time that the work will be published even if he/she graduates or that the supervisor has lost contact with the student or that there has been a falling out.  The supervisor is also kind enough to place the student as the first author.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus I cannot understand how you can think this is acceptable/normal.

Comment: @QuantumBrick The supervisor has as much ownership as the student.  Do you think it is ok for a student to dump years of research, which the supervisor has invested time in, down the drain?  It would be bad if the student is not included as an author or not the first author.  In this case, the supervisor is salvaging his/her work, and very generously placed the student as the first author.  It seems like the only issue is that the supervisor didn't inform the student -- there are many reason for this.  E.g., I don't tell Mrs Claus every time I take a piss.

Comment: @QuantumBrick In my opinion, the student should be grateful for having a paper published without doing work!  The student should thank the supervisor for getting the paper published.

Comment: @Ootagu disagree.  'advisor is a hired position the student pays for'? are you kidding? if I get funding to hire a student to help me realized my idea, and the student disappears, don't I have the responsibility to my stakeholders?  Also, 'work belongs to the student' is not correct unless the supervisor is never involved in the project.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus The student should not necessarily be grateful for having a paper of poor quality published in a journal of poor reputation, with their name on it but without being informed. The least the advisor should have done is to inform the student *before* publication, so they can at least object to their name being attached to it.

Comment: I know that the answer is not acceptable. But, as strange it might seems, it can be also perfectly acceptable. Not to say welcomed.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus formally a PhD thesis is a single-author work. Outright copying a section and publishing it under names other than the student's smells like plagiarism to me.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus, I add my voice to the others who are baffled by your opinion and attempted arguments to support it. If someone put your name on a manuscript you disapproved of and published it without consulting you, would you be calmed by "I don't tell you when I take a piss" or "you should be grateful"?

Comment: @QuantumBrick I think the situation is quite different, if the possibility Prof.SantaClaus raises is true, that the advisor and student at some point early on had discussed publishing this work. OP says "without my knowledge" which is a little ambiguous, it could just mean they discussed publication, years passed, and without notifying the student the advisor went ahead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is obviously not ok to publish the work of someone else without asking all authors. It is also certainly startling to see it done in such an apparently careless manner (as an unedited copy of a thesis chapter that doesn’t conform to the standards of the publication journal - and still somehow gets published). So what happened is puzzling.

Realistically, there is nothing you could have done to prevent it from happening. Given how strange this story is, you couldn’t have been expected to explicitly tell your adviser to please not do what they did. Maybe they meant well, maybe they did it to add a publication to their own record, but they shouldn’t have done this as they did.

What this means to you depends on details you don’t mention in your question (e.g., are you in industry or academia, did you plan to use your thesis work in other ways, are you worried about what you consider a sub-par publication).

Comment: Correct. _Absolutely_ not ok.

Comment: And was this a predatory journal or a legitimate one?

Comment: @B.Goddard This is a legitimate journal. The thesis chapter that ended being in the paper contained some valuable analyses, but wasn't edited in an optimized way for journal submission in terms of concision and organization, though I guess it didn't matter that much as it ended up being published.

Comment: I think I'd write a serious letter to the journal, then.  Something slipped (the editor is a buddy of one of the authors, or someone is not paying attention to standards) and they need to know about it.

Comment: @B.Goddard just bear in mind you might burn bridges with your former supervisor. Not that it should matter, given their record, but still bear that in mind.